# pstricks-add: set seed for psRandom

Tags: pstricks-add

The figure shown below contains "dots" scattered randomly using *\psRandom* from the  *pstricks-add* package. I need the capability of regenerating the same pattern for several figures (and in time, gif animations). Moreover, I also want to find a seed that produces a "better" set of "dots".

I am using *psRandom* because I am new to *pstricks* and, apart from being able to select the seed, it has exactly the functionality I need. (I did have a look at the *pstricks-add* manual (from 2004) but it does not mention it as a possible option.)

Does anyone have a suggestion to how I can fix this? I imagine that the seed is set in a variable that I should be able to overwrite...

[image]

I am open to alternatives not involving psRandom. However, I am trying to move away from tikz and I am therefore looking for a solution using pstricks.

Thank you very much for your help. The tex file shown below will reproduce the figure.

```
% summary: Figure containing random dots...
%
%          execute the following commands sequentially in order to typeset.
%          $ latex texput.tex
%          $ dvips texput.dvi
%          $ ps2pdf texput.ps

\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}

\begin{document}
%
 \begin{pspicture}*(-5.5,-5.5)(7.5,5.5)
    \def\myFrame{5cm}
    \def\myWidth{8pt}
    \def\myGreen{green!80!black}
    \def\myMagenta{magenta}
    \def\myCyan{cyan!90!black}
    \def\myBlack{black!70!gray}
% Magenta dots
\psRandom[dotstyle=o, fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=\myMagenta,%
linecolor=\myGreen, randomPoints=20, dotsize=\myWidth]%
(-\myFrame,-\myFrame)%
( \myFrame, \myFrame)%
{\psframe[linecolor=black](-\myFrame,-\myFrame)(\myFrame,\myFrame)}
% Cyan dots
\psRandom[dotstyle=o,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=\myCyan,linecolor=\myGreen,%
randomPoints=4,dotsize=\myWidth]%
(-\myFrame,-\myFrame)%
( \myFrame, \myFrame)%
{\psframe[linecolor=black](-\myFrame,-\myFrame)(\myFrame,\myFrame)}
% Black dots
\psRandom[dotstyle=o,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=\myBlack,linecolor=\myBlack,%
randomPoints=2,dotsize=\myWidth]%
( 5,-5)%
( 7, 5)%
{\psframe[linecolor=black,linestyle=dashed]( 5, -5)( 7, 5)}
 \end{pspicture}
%
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The file `pstricks-add.tex` initialized the random number generator by the command

```
rrand srand
```

in the macro `\psRandom@iii`.

To make the result reproducible, we need to change `rrand` to any constant number, say, 42.

Put in the preamble of your document (*after* `\usepackage{pstricks-add}`)

```
\makeatletter
\def\psRandom@iii(#1)(#2)#3{%
  \def\pst@tempA{#3}%
  \ifx\pst@tempA\pst@empty\psclip{\psframe(#2)}\else\psclip{#3}\fi
  \pst@getcoor{#1}\pst@tempA 
  \pst@getcoor{#2}\pst@tempB 
  \begin@SpecialObj
  \addto@pscode{
    \pst@tempA\space /yMin exch def 
    /xMin exch def
    \pst@tempB\space /yMax exch def 
    /xMax exch def 
    /dy yMax yMin sub def
    /dx xMax xMin sub def
    42 srand                 % initializes the random generator
    /getRandReal { rand 2147483647 div } def
    \psk@dotsize % defines /DS ... def
    \@nameuse{psds@\psk@dotstyle}
    \psk@randomPoints {
     \ifPst@color getRandReal getRandReal getRandReal setrgbcolor \fi
     getRandReal dx mul xMin add
     getRandReal dy mul yMin add
     Dot
     \ifx\psk@fillstyle\psfs@solid fill \fi stroke
    } repeat
  }%
  \end@SpecialObj
  \endpsclip
  \ignorespaces
}
\makeatother
```

Comment: I keep on being amazed of how much knowledge many of you have.  

May I suggest a couple of additions:  

Just after "makealetter" add the following two lines:  
`\define@key[psset]{pstricks-add}{setSeed}[0]{\pst@checknum{#1}\psk@setSeed}`  
and `\psset[pstricks-add]{setSeed=0}`  

Replace 42srand by:  
`\psk@setSeed\space cvi dup 0 eq { pop rrand } if srand`  


Now the seed can be set easily using:  

`\psRandom[setSeed=42,...](xmin,ymin)(xmax,ymax){}`

Comment: It is a good suggestion.  Maybe you could send it to Herbert Voss who maintains pstricks-add