# How to seed PSTricks' pseudo-random generator?

Tags: pstricks

Is it possible to fix, once and for all, the results that one gets by the Rand function in PSTricks? If I like the shape of the points after one compilation then I don't want to get different points next time.

Comment: You may need to update the random number generator by providing it with a fixed number. That will make it reproducible. See [pstricks-add: set seed for psRandom](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/233903/5764).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `\pstVerb{realtime srand}` in the preamble (the space between `\documentclass` and `\begin{document}` to seed the pseudo random generator.

For more details, invoke [this search query](https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A87876%20srand).

Comment: Thank you very much! This was exactly what I wanted.